# How to write redirect rule without .html, few slashes and question mark on Nginx?

Tags: nginx, redirect

I need to 301 redirect from site.com/index.html to site.com/, site.com// (or more slashes) to site.com/ and site.com/? to site.com/

I tried to search for information on the Internet, but could not find what I needed.

thank you